# Expo Go works, but Eas Build dosnt work the app

Tags: android, react-native, request, expo, eas

Im new using RN and Expo go. I create a app that when it open in the first screen shows info that he get from my backend. When I use expo go the app works fine in ios and android, everything good, even with cellphone internet so its not a problem with the Cors. But when I run the eas build to get a apk and installed to a android or emulator when the app opens all the UI works fine but every screen that have a api so he can show the info is not working.

[image]

I put some debugs in the code to see if there is a error in the request but i dont see the problem.
I dont know what is the problem.
[image]

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-updates": "^0.18.17",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-md5": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.2",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried to uninstall expo updates cause i see other guy saying thats work for him.
Tried to see if the endpoint was the problem but is not, since i can see the api info directly form the browser in my cellphone with my cellphone data, so the cors is correctly setted, and the other think is that all the apis i have dosnt need credentials.